# Why do I need an implementation file (.m) when creating project-wide constants?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants, header-files

At the moment I create constants in this way:

```
// Constants.h
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const kTestConstant;

// Constants.m
NSString *const kTestConstant = @"TestConstant";
```

This of course works fine, however I'm puzzled on why I can't just have it all in the header file like this:

```
NSString *const kTestConstant = @"TestConstant";
```

If I do that, include Constants.h in various classes and use kTestConstant in those classes, I get redefinition errors at compile time. Why is that?

My theory is that by having a constant only on a header file, the file Constants.h is 'copy-pasted' into the class files that import it, consequently I end up with two copies of kTestConstant. However, by using an implementation file, that file is compiled and linked with the classes that import Constants.h. Is this more or less correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially your analysis is correct except for the "modern" concept of "paste". The compilation unit is a concatenation of all header files directly or indirectly included/imported and the implementation file.

As always I recommend obtaining a good "C" language book and studying it, Objective-C is just a thin layer on top of "C". That is what I did years ago, still have the book.

Comment: But with objective C, with the directive "import", the files are imported only ones, and in "C", with the directive "include" the header files are protected with an include guard.

Comment: @samir The files are imported only once per compilation unit. If there are multiple compilation units that import the same file each will import the file. `#import` protects against a compilation unit from including the same file multiple times due to circular reverences and multiple references to it. `#include` does not provide this protection and "guard` defined are generally used to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: OK thanks for the clear answer.What is your best "C" book please ?

Comment: I have to go with the K&R book and unfortunately it is expensive in the print version, the Kindle version is more reasonable. My favorite is out of print. Hopefully some others will add their favorites.